# dput structure not loading properly

Tags: r, structure

I have downloaded this data file https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D315881_05804680_037112 (from this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148065/what-do-the-the-lsmeans-from-lsmeans-package-in-r-represent-when-calculated-ov) which contains dput output and opened it in geany text editor. From here I copied the entire structure and tried to paste it on the R command prompt. But it is not getting pasted properly and breaking at one particular line which does not seem to have any problem otherwise.

```
+ "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", 
+ "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "136", "137", "139", 
+ "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", 
+ "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
+ "220", "221", "222", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", 
+ "230", "231", "232
+ "239", "240", "241"), class = "factor"), fixationImage = structu
Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
""230", "231", "232
"239"
> 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "2L,"
> 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "1L,"
> 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
Error: unexpected ',' in "6L,"
> 
> 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L,
```

What could be the cause and how can I sort this out?

Comment: The console buffer size problem, I guess.

Comment: How can I solve it. I tried some internet search links but not able to make out how to do in for R prompt.

Comment: Use `dget("lookDATA.txt")` maybe.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Why don't you put these few lines as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly paste large `dput()` output might hit the wall of the console buffer size. One way is to save the `dput()` out in a text file, then use the function `dget()`.

With the above example, this leads to:

```
dget("lookDATA.txt")
```

Comment: Any way to actually increase buffer size to be able to paste larger structures?

Comment: I am not sure. I just checked, and pasting `dput()` output in both R (3.2.0) running in terminal (GNOME terminal 3.6.2) and in RStudio (0.98.1103) worked.

Comment: I am running Linux Debian Stable with KDE Konsole version 2.8.4

Comment: Sorry, this is out the range of my expertise.